# Cuckoo Hashing Cycle detection and rehash?

Tags: c, hash, hashtable

When trying to insert a certain key into my hash table in **Cuckoo hashing**, sometimes you would hit the so-called cycle where the same key is getting kicked out and inserted back in repeatedly, meaning we find the same initial situation as at the beginning again.

To avoid that, I am trying to grow the size of my table by a certain amount when a cycle is detected, but after that what does it mean to `rehash`? Or as I have read in several documents, `rehash` is a different function that needs to be performed if the original `insertion` process fails.

I am a bit confused as to why do you need a `rehash`. Wouldn't grow the size of the table and call the original insertion process again (this time with the updated table size) suffice the purpose?

Comment: I think that the hash function works modulo the table size, so if you change the table size, then you must put everything already in the table in its new position relative to he table size. That is a "rehash".

Comment: @PaulOgilvie so do you think can the same insertion function be applied after its new table size? (to rehash)

Comment: I think it is time for you to google "cuckoo hashing" and read the articles.